# How to make logger interpret carriage returns like they would appear on the screen?

Tags: python, logging, carriage-return

I'm receiving a progress status from a serial port and I will like to interpret the carriage return like a print will look like on the screen, before logging in file using python logger.

Truncated example:

```
receivedData = "command x exec: \nin progress    0/8192\rin progress 8096/8192\rin progress 8128/8192\rin progress 8160/8192\rin progress 8192/8192\nDONE"
```

I will like the result string to look like this:
`"command x exec: \nin progress 8192/8192\nDONE"` to have a logger file that looks like:

```
command x exec: 
in progress 8192/8192
DONE
```

Instead of the result if I log directly `receivedData`:

```
command x exec: 
in progress    0/8192
in progress 8096/8192
in progress 8128/8192
in progress 8160/8192
in progress 8192/8192
DONE
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve that?

Comment: Please update your question and provide a [mre] of it not doing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex to remove the parts you don't want:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('^.*\r', '', receivedData, flags=re.M)
'command x exec: \nin progress 8192/8192\nDONE'
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - Start of line (in the context of [`re.M`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.M))
- `.*` - Zero or more characters